# Program ends before async result is received

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, spotify

I am writing a program to interact with the Spotify API via a command line.

I have some code here to take a command, and then execute the relevant function to retrieve data from Spotify.

This code shows the problem, I have left out irrelevant code.

```
public class CommandHandler
{
    public async void HandleCommands()
    {
        var spotifyCommand = GetCommand();

        if (spotifyCommand == SpotifyCommand.Current)
        {
            WriteCurrentSong(await new PlayerController().GetCurrentlyPlayingAsync());
        }

        if (spotifyCommand == SpotifyCommand.NextTrack)
        {
            WriteCurrentSong(await new PlayerController().NextTrackAsync());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
        //end of program
    }
}

public class PlayerController
{
    public async Task<SpotifyCurrentlyPlaying> NextTrackAsync()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            //removed code to set headers etc

            //Skip Track
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/next", null);

            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
            {
                //code to handle this case, not important
            }
            
            return await GetCurrentlyPlayingAsync();
        }
    }

    public async Task<SpotifyCurrentlyPlaying> GetCurrentlyPlayingAsync()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            //removed code to set headers etc
            
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing");

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SpotifyCurrentlyPlaying>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
    }
}
```

The two if statements in `HandleCommands()` call into PlayerController and await the result of the method. For some reason if I use `await PlayerController.MethodCall()` the call is made, however, the result does not return before the program finishes executing.

Strangely, this is not an issue if I use `PlayerController.MethodCall().Result`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, as I would really rather not use `.Result`. Thanks!

Comment: Unless HandleCommands is an event hander (and it doesn't look like), the signature should be `async Task`, not `async void`.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. I'll be sure to change it. Do you think that will have an effect on the problem discussed above? Or is that just a code design improvement?

Comment: It is extremely likely.  Any thrown exception can't be caught properly with async void and you can't properly wait for its completion.

Comment: `console.ReadLine()` **outside** the async method

Comment: Ahh ok, thank you @DavidL

Comment: But nothing is returned @Charlieface, in fact it doesn't even get to that Console.ReadLine(). I have checked, there are no exceptions thrown as far as I can see. The application just quits.

Comment: async function `await`s on a background thread. Control returns to calling function `main()`, which ends the foreground thread and exiting the app before the `await` returns. Move `console.ReadLine()` to `Main()`

Comment: [_HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use._](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1#examples). Also respect `IDisposable HttpResponseMessage` `using(var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(...)) { ... }`.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying now @Charlieface, I'll amend it.

Comment: @Charlieface - asynchronous methods (which access external resources) are executed on the same single thread as other code. This is a beauty of  `async-await` that we don't need to "waste" extra threads which doing nothing but only waiting for a response from external resource.

Comment: Only up to the `await`. When the `await` returns, it depends on the settings of the `SynchronizationContext` and whether `ConfigureAwait(false)` is used. Either way it makes no difference, as control has already returned to `Main()` as I described

Comment: More info: [avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signature of the `HandleCommands` is an issue

```
public async void HandleCommands()
{ 
  // ...
}
```

You are not showing how this method is called, but I assume it is something like below:

```
var handler = new CommandHandler();
handler.HandleCommands();
```

Because of `async void` method doesn't return `Task` and caller can not "observe" it's completion.
So application finishes without waiting for task to complete.

To fix - change method signature to below and await for task to complete

```
public async Task HandleCommands()
{ 
  // ...
}

var handler = new CommandHandler();
await handler.HandleCommands();
```

Comment: This has solved the issue, thank you! I didn't know the difference between the two signatures had that much of an impact.